# Auto sync Azure SQL DB data to Azure search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I want to sync any DML operations on Azure SQL DB to azure search index immediately.

I have gone through this question.
[How does Auto-indexing/sync of Azure SQL DB with Azure Search Works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637939/how-does-auto-indexing-sync-of-azure-sql-db-with-azure-search-works)

No answer in this question. This was posted almost 5 yrs back.
With integrated change policy in place do we have auto sync feature by any means now.

Function app does not have a SQL trigger event attached.

I don't want to do a while true loop or any timer or call indexer when data gets update.
Please suggest if there are any other best approach or any build feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions don't have a SQL trigger but Logic Apps do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure Logic Apps can also trigger functions and custom APIs, so you should be able to trigger an indexing operation from a SQL operation this way. Do keep in mind however that the indexing process itself may be delayed or take time once triggered so your index may not immediately reflect the changes, depending on payload.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Any idea how I can link logic app to incremental changes with sql interested change policy?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can integrate Azure SQL data with Azure Search.

**Built-in indexer.** You have the built-in index support for Azure SQL. It supports incremental updating of the index, but with a limited refresh ratio. Currently, you can run incremental indexing every 5 minutes at the most. See [Connect to and index Azure SQL content using an Azure Cognitive Search indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers)

**Push API.** To support *immediate updates*, you have to push data via the Push API. In this case you only create the *index*, not the *indexer*. Your code that pushes content to Azure SQL is responsible for pushing content to Azure Search. Check out this example [Tutorial: Optimize indexing with the push API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api)

Comment: Thanks @Dan. That example looks like it is for the first time indexing. Any pointers to immediately updating the index?

Comment: The Push API example shows you how to immediately update content. There is a difference in creating a record for the first time and updating the record. You control this by selecting the so-called indexing action. I.e. you can use upload when you create a new record, merge if you update an existing record or simply mergeOrUpload to handle both at once. 

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-what-is-data-import#indexing-actions